# Bootstrap 4 - how to use media query mixin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

How do I set a media breakpoint let's say from medium to large - do I nest the min mixin and max mixin or how do I do that.

the output I'm after is something like this: @media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) using the breakpoint mixin.

Answer (score 58):

Use `media-breakpoint-between($lower, $upper)`

**Dependencies**

The mixins are declared in `mixins/_breakpoints.scss`, and depend on the $grid-breakpoints map, found in `_variables.scss`.

## Example

**Breakpoint map:**

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
)
```

**Mixin:**

```
@include media-breakpoint-between(sm, md) {
    // your code
}
```

**Compiles to**

```
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 991px) {}
```

**Important notice**

Media-breakpoint-between mixin uses 'lower' and 'upper' values of declared breakpoint.

- The 'lower' value of breakpoint is the declared value in
  $grid-breakpoint map.
- The 'upper' value of specific breakpoint is equal to the value of
  higher breakpoint minus 1px.

**Upper & lower breakpoint values example** (based od $grid-breakpoint map)

```
Lower value of md is equal to 576
Upper value of md is equal to 991 ( value of next breakpoint (lg) minus 1px (992px-1px)
```

**Other media mixins**

`@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {}` creates a breakpoint with a min-width of `$sm`.

`@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {}` creates a breakpoint with a max-width of `$md`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is also mixin `media-breakpoint-between($lower, $upper)`

So this should work

```
@include media-breakpoint-between(sm, md){
  // this applies only between the sm and ms breakpoints 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do a combo of two classes.
(Also BS4 uses rems now not px.)

Example... 
(From: http://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/jbEGWb)

```
<!-- Jay's Viewport Helper -->
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);padding:10px;color:#fff;">
  <span class="hidden-sm-up">SIZE XS</span>
  <span class="hidden-xs-down hidden-md-up">SIZE SM</span>
  <span class="hidden-sm-down hidden-lg-up">SIZE MD</span>
  <span class="hidden-md-down hidden-xl-up">SIZE LG</span>
  <span class="hidden-lg-down">SIZE XL</span>
</div>
<!-- /Jay's Viewport Helper -->
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He wants to use the media mixin in an SCSS file that compiles to a media query.