# Media breakpoints not working on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a wordpress page using the bootstrap-four theme

I can't seem to get the media breakpoints to work. At the end of my custom stylesheet (style.css) I tried:

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
   body {
     color: red;
   }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  body {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media screen (min-width: 576px) {
  body {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  body {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

I made sure that `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` is in the `<head>...</head>`

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong @media mixin. Use @media only screen and (min-width : ---px)

Example mobile first:

https://jsfiddle.net/g8awz9g4/1/

Code:

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```

Example: desktop -> mobile

https://jsfiddle.net/g8awz9g4/2/

code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 979px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

Comment: That works (although the effect I want is with max-width), but why doesn't `@include media-breakpoint-down(xs)` work with bootstrap?

Comment: Added max-width for you, do you have _breakpoints.scss included see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545506/bootstrap-4-how-to-use-media-query-mixing

Comment: The question is about the mixin supplied in BS4, so although your styles work it's not really what he is asking - as per @Marc comment above check the correct SCSS is included.