# Remove element when screen size decreases wordpress

Tags: responsive-design

I'd like to completely remove my map from this

http://beyondmyborder.com/destinations/

when the screen size decreases.

Div Id :

```
id="mapdiv"
```

Thank you!

Comment: What size? and did you try anything yourself or are you just asking someone to do your task.

Comment: I'm hoping to decrease the map with the size of the the screen until screen is 560px, then disappear.  Of course, no one is required to help. I'm only hoping for some assistance since I couldn't figure it out myself, thank you.

Comment: Did you manage it?

Comment: Thank you so much! Will give it a try now !

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do a specific action with CSS you need media queries. I suggest you google media queries to get an idea what they do and how they work. I also got an example below. Media queries are basically a statement that execute when the screen width matches the queries. For example if the screen is smaller than 1200px or 979px.

[Media breakpoints not working on wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974983/media-breakpoints-not-working-on-wordpress/42975032#42975032)

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 979px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

In your case you want a custom media query at 560px:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 560px) {
   #mapdiv {
      display: none;
   }
}
```

What this does; when the screen size is below 560px width. it will execute/overwrite the css. What we say is div with the id: mapdiv add the css rule: display none (hide the element).

To get the mediaqueries/viewport working you also need to add this line in your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Thanks again! @Marc