# How Do I build Bootstrap 4 with a Desktop First approach in mind

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Simple Question: Bootstrap is now "Mobile-First". How do i change it back to "Desktop First" and by this I mean using the "Screen is lower than" approach rather than "screen is higher than". they do give some hints of this inside their own documentation with the media-breakpoint-down mixins, but I havent been able to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Later Edit: My question is just how do i modify the original files so I can get this result when I just build the bootstrap dist files with the npm build command from cmd. Thats all. I write my own css in a .css file separate from the bootstrap

Later Edit2: In case i wasnt clear with what I want, when you build bootstrap, the default it's using the @media-breakpoint-up system when it builds the media queries and how it's structuring the compiled css (no media query for mobile, min-width:576px and so on upwards). How do i make it compile it in reverse using @media-breakpoint-down so its no media query for above 1200px then lg for max 1199, and so on and do forth on the way down.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545506/bootstrap-4-how-to-use-media-query-mixing

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(xs) { 
   //your code
 }
```

That will translate to:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
   //your code
}
```

Where options are `xs, sm, md, lg, xl` for specific screens.

Comment: WIll this apply to how columns are structured, for example if I have col-md-3, it will only apply to that specific resolution and LOWER rather than that specific resolution and higher?

Comment: No this will not change it, but you can use it to create your style as desktop first. Bootstrap classes will stay the same, it cannot be changed without deep cut into the core of bootstrap and I don't think it is necessary.