# Customize Bootstrap 4 media queries in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to customize Bootstrap 4 media queries (add a new xxl media query).

Based on this solution, [Bootstrap 4 - how to use media query mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545506/bootstrap-4-how-to-use-media-query-mixin), I try to define new $grid-breakpoints but it doesn't affect Bootstrap behavior.

I have used the gem install of Bootstrap.

It seems that the problem is that Bootstrap doesn't use the new media queries and I don't know how to explicitly include Bootstrap files in my stylesheets (to use Bootstrap mixins and functions). The installation of Bootstrap is located in

```
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.beta2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all [bootstrap-rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) recommends using scss for your application stylesheet.

Create a file which will hold all the bootstrap overrides, let's say `bootstrap_overrides.scss`, and copy/paste and modify any variables you want from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss), in your case it should be like this:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1500px
) !default;
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1440px
) !default;
```

Then simply import your overrides to `application.scss` **before** bootstrap, like this:

```
@import "bootstrap_overrides";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to copy/paste and modify the bootstrap 4 scss variables provided by the gem here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss

From line `161`:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
```

Comment: I already tried to replace these values but it doesn't affect page behavior.

Comment: We solved the bug. We were importing in application.css 
 *= require lib/lib_override
 *= require lib/lib 
lib had bootstrap and lib_override the new media queries / container width.
The new sizes need to be in the same file that bootstrap import. So in lib.scss we now have 

- 'before_lib' import
- 'bootstrap-grid' import

with before_lib.scss

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1500px
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1440px
) !default;

Comment: I can create an answer if the formating is not clear, thanks